# composer install issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting following error message while I am trying to execute 'composer install' command in my cmd.

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.jso
n. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for classpreloader/classpreloader 2.0.0 -> satisfiabl
e by classpreloader/classpreloader[2.0.0].
    - classpreloader/classpreloader 2.0.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP versi
on (5.5.6) or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.1.8 -> satisfiable by larave
l/framework[v5.1.8].
    - laravel/framework v5.1.8 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.5.6)
or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - laravel/framework v5.1.8 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.5.6)
or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laracasts/generators 1.1.1 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable
 by laravel/framework[v5.1.8].
    - Installation request for laracasts/generators 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by lara
casts/generators[1.1.1].
```

Thanks

Comment: did you read the error message? follow its solution?

Comment: php composer.phar update try that

Answer (score 3):

This line tells you what your error is:

> laravel/framework v5.1.8 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.5.6)
>   or "config.platform.php" value does not satisfy that requirement.

It says that some of the packages you are trying to install require PHP version 5.5.9 or greater and you are using version 5.5.6

You need to update to a newer version of PHP.

Comment: Doesn't seem like he's going to mark yours as the answer but this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to force it  using

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

but it'll install code  without checking  php version  - really not recomended (code may not work ) , butter  upgrade php version